# Ошибка при запуске теста xlsx создания

Tags: java, apache, xls, xlsx, poi

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Хотя библиотке poi скачал полностью и добавил в проект . 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Возможно у вас в зависимостях есть старая библиотека xmlbeans, нужно посмотреть перечень всех библиотек. Как вы собираете проект?

Answer (score 0):

Работаем мы в SOA 12c и на сервере на который устанавливается web-service стояла стандартная библиотека , в которой был xmlbeans и он мешал  сборке .